# Does splitting the clock signal into several inputs cause problems with system stability?

Tags: digital-logic

Below is the schematic of the sequencer I designed. Does splitting the clock signal into several inputs cause problems with system stability? I have marked with colour the place where the signal was split. Is this the right way? Or should I do it differently? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: I see no real problem with the splitting of the clock. Why did you think there would be? I can see other potential problems though - no filtering of the inputs is one. Why so retro - grandpa wants his design back! A modern solution might use an Arduino or suchlike.

Comment: @Kartman Thanks. What do you mean by filtering of the inputs?

Comment: The counters can clock at 1MHz or so. You need to ensure your input signals don’t have noise, glitches or bounces that would cause the counters to count faster than you expect.

Comment: @Kartman I will clock not so fast. Neither the internal nor external signals are noise-free and have an ideal level thanks to the Schmitt trigger inverters. Thanks for your advices.

Comment: Splitting clocks can cause issues, namely if the clock is fast due to terminations, propagation time or loading. It is one of the reason clock fanout exist. I think you can get away with it in this case though. But just in case, leave some positions for series at the driver and around the node resistors so you can terminate if necessary.

Comment: @JerzyPrzezdziecki filtering is not for the speed of your signal/clock, it's for noise that's not part of your signal, and it's for dampening the speed of your clock edge so that the ringing and forth and back travel don't kill you. Your clock has way higher bandwidth than it's clock frequency!

Comment: but I do kind of agree with Kartman – this would be as complex as having a single microcontroller, and maybe two external shift registers to control your  32 LEDs in total, plus of course the inevitable LEDs and series resistors (unless your shift register is a constant current sink one). What you build is really impressively complex for such a simple task. Throw in a linear regulator, and a total of 5 capacitors, und this would easily fit onto the cap of a bottle of your favourite fizzy drink.

Comment: by the way, the schematic has a very pretty aesthetic to it. Might I ask with what you've drawn this?

Comment: @MarcusMüller Thanks. This circuit is an experimental music sequencer which sends 8  triggers outputs. The potentiometer is a source of voltage, which, with the help of ADC, I convert into binary pattern combinations, which are written to each of the 64 memory addresses. The external clock switches address with 8-bit patterns.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I use Eagle.

Comment: Lots of hazards in that circuit!

Comment: @BruceAbbott Please explain. The circuit works and tested a few weeks. Could you point it out?

Comment: The pink is just a simple forced metastable with hysteresis and inverter delay to reset all on the same input edge.  fun little flashie converter ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your clocking arrangement is difficult to analyze by inspection. You generate a "clock" signal, pass it through an inverter and use that as the inverted clock for IC10. IC10's output is passed through an RC network, two Schmitt inverters and then IC11. An output of IC11 is then fed all the way back to the reset input of IC3, which is clocked on the original non-inverted clock, and IC5, which gets one of your inverted clocks.

I would be concerned about the timing relationship between the reset input and the clock input of IC3 and IC5. You need to make sure there are no setup or hold problems that could occur. You should draw a timing diagram for this signal path, adding the minimum and maximum delays of each element in the path, and see what the relationship is between the two inputs of IC3 and IC5.

Comment: Thanks you are right. The inverter IC9C is not needed. I will try to analyze the path as you suggested.